# system.nullreferenceexception 'object reference not set to an instance of an object.' vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

i get this whenever i run this specific form and i do not know why this keep showing, pls help me how to solve this i do not know how to, i do not know what this means but as far as i know my other forms work perfectly fine

```
system.nullreferenceexception 'object reference not set to an instance of an object.' vb.net
```

This is the code:

```
public database as ADODB.Connection
public table as ADODB.RecordSet
Private Sub frmSales_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        database.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Windows10\Downloads\FinalsProject.accdb")
        table.Open("select * from TB_Transactions", database, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
        table.MoveFirst()

        Call DisplayRecord()
        Call DisabledControl()
 End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZgx4.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your must init `database`, `table` before use:

```
 database = New ADODB.Connection()
 table = New ADODB.Recordset()
```